# Query category-specific, paginated posts and allow viewer to change sort order

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, sort, order

Maybe this has already been asked here, but I can't seem to find a solution, so forgive me if this is a duplicate.

I have coded a custom template to display all posts from a category with the ID 36.  I would then like to provide the viewer with the option to sort the displayed posts either alphabetically or chronologically.

Everything is working fine - the posts are displaying correctly and are paginated - but I can't get the sorting links to work.

Some help with this would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap" class="fullwidth">
    <div class="hfeed" id="content">
        <div id="headline">
            <?php $sort= $_GET['sort'];
                if($sort == "title")
                {
                $order= "orderby=title";
                }
                if($sort == "date")
                {
                $order= "orderby=date";
                }
            ?>
            <h1>My Headline</h1>
            <h2>My sub-headline.</h2>
            <a href="?sort=title">Sort by Title</a>
            <a href="?sort=date">Sort by Date</a>
        </div>
        <div id="video_gallery">
            <?php 
                $temp = $wp_query; 
                $wp_query = null; 
                $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
                $wp_query->query('cat=36&posts_per_page=6'.'&paged='.$paged.$order.'&order=DEC'); 
            ?>
            <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );?>
                <div class="video_item">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="play_button"></div>
                        <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="video_image"/>
                    </a>
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="video_title"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
                        <span class="video_date"><?php the_date(); ?></span>
                    </p>
                    <div class="videoExcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="watch_video">Watch Video ></a>
                </div><!-- .video_item -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <center id="paginate"><?php posts_nav_link( ' ', '<img src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/metric/images/prev.png" />', '<img src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/metric/images/next.png" />' ); ?></center>
            <?php 
                $wp_query = null; 
                $wp_query = $temp;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #video_gallery -->
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #content-sidebar-wrap -->
```

I should add that PHP and Wordpress are not my areas of specialty, so any other input you may have about my above code is also more than welcome.  Thank you!

Comment: `showposts` is depreciated, you should use `posts_per_page`

Comment: Thanks, @PieterGoosen!  I'll make that change now and edit my question to reflect it.

Comment: What sorting links are you talking about?

Comment: I would like to add an option at the top of my page, to allow the viewer to sort the displayed posts by date or alphabetically.  I have updated my question, to clarify this.